# MKMapView in table cell: Make whole cell clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

I have a table with several cells and all should be clickable. And all are...but in one cell I have a MKMapView. And in that cell not only a click on the part of the cell not containing the map but also a click directly on the map should trigger the event "clicked cell"...but it doesn't...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to be able to interact with the map? If not, you can disable user interaction from it. `mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Comment: Nope I don't need to interact with the map..it should be just an "image" and the edit will be made in the next (segued) view controller. But I already disabled user interaction, doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling everything inside the cell

```
for(UIView * cellSubviews in cell.subviews)
{
    cellSubviews.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: I am using storyboard so I just tried to disable user interaction on the content view and it worked. Thanks